# Can't set static IP on Ubuntu

Tags: 13.10, configuration, static-ip, nic

I recently installed Ubuntu Desktop 13.10 and I am trying to set up static IP by changing the `/etc/network/interfaces` file from:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)                                                                                                                        
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet dynamic
```

to:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)                                                                                                                        
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.70
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
network 192.168.1.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

Using whatever I gleaned from these FAQ/Tutorial Sites

- [Ubuntu Network Configuration](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html)
- [problem with static ip in ubuntu 12.04 lts server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/326461/problem-with-static-ip-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts-server)
- [Linux Basics - Set A Static IP On Ubuntu](http://www.howtoforge.com/linux-basics-set-a-static-ip-on-ubuntu)
- [Howto: Ubuntu Linux convert DHCP network configuration to static IP configuration](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-ubuntu-linux-convert-dhcp-network-configuration-to-static-ip-configuration.html)

I have double checked those numbers, and they are the same values I use on 2 different computers at the office (NOTE: those 2 computers, raspis, are connected to a network switch then the router, whereas the desktop currently in question connect directly to the router). However, when I enable static addresses and restart, the machine does not get the ip address I requested (`192.168.1.70`), instead <s>getting a different one (`192.168.1.111`)</s> disabling the NIC altogether. I have also tried requesting a different ip address (`192.168.1.199`) in case the old one was taken, but that too results in the NIC being disabled.

I am asking this question here as google/SO does not seem to have an answer specifically pertaining to what users should do, and how they should proceed when simply "googling the problem" and quickly updating a single file does not result in static addresses. I am specifically requesting the following:

1. An answer as to why this may not be working (ie. whether this is Ubuntu 13.10 related).
2. How to debug the network initialization during boot.
3. How to finally set up static ip addressing.

**EDIT:**

As per Atari's requests, I tried setting the IP using the GUI instead of the command line. To do this, I had to purge the `/etc/network/interfaces` file first (by commenting out the static related lines), restarting, then trying again. If I do not do this, I can not even access the options of my NIC. This did assign a static IP to my computer, however, now I only have local access to and from it (via `ssh`) with absolutely no access to the internet.

Comment: Do you have the desktop installed on the problem computer? Or are you working CLI only?

Comment: @Atari911 I have the desktop installed, out of preference I am using the terminal to update this file

Comment: Thats what i was wondering. Have you tried to change it using the GUI? Just to check that works?

Comment: @Atari911 I will try that and edit the question to include the outcome

Comment: It seems like maybe there is another program that is taking the network settings from some other config. Im thinking this because you are good until you reboot.

Comment: @Atari911 Oh man I really messed up on account of having 2 ethernet cards. Turns out if I set up static addressing the NIC fails and I have **no** internet. I added a strikeout to address this. Sorry

Comment: @Atari911 your suggestion worked when using the GUI. Add it as an answer and I will accept it if you like. Also, any idea why this is happening? I don't feel comfortable using a GUI version without understanding why the command line version failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the line which will cause the configuration to be run at startup.

Edit your `/etc/network/interfaces` configuration and add the line:

```
auto eth0
```

In the mean time, you can set the static address with the command:

```
sudo ifup eth0
```

It you want to have the interface to start only when you are connected to a specific network, check the documentation and examples for the `ifupdown` package.  In particular, look at the `mapping` command.   The `ping-places.sh` command can be useful in identifying which network you are on.

Comment: Can you be more specific when you say `Edit your configuration`...which configuration? `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Comment: @puk I've edited the post to be more specific.

Comment: This may be entering the realm of stupid question, but should I remove any other `auto` commands already in there, like `auto lo`

Comment: I think it was the fact that I was missing `auto eth0`. It *seems* to be working at the moment

Answer (score 2):

I would try to use the GUI to set the static IP. If that works then you know that you are using the `NetworkManager` package to control that NICs IP. The package should disable itself for the interface if it is mentioned in the manual config (as per: https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkManager) But that seems to not be happening.

You can also remove the `NetworkManager` completely with...

`sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome`

`sudo apt-get remove network-manager`

...and then attempt to change it manually.

Comment: Also, now that you mentioned having two NICs... Make sure that you are referencing the correct interface in the config. NetworkManager will disable for that interface only if it is explicitly mentioned in the /etc/network/interfaces.

Comment: That's a good idea actually as eth1 is not mentioned in `/etc/network/interfaces`, only eth0

Comment: Thank you for all your help, but ultimately I will have to go with BillThor's answer as I am pretty sure I was missing `auto eth0`

Comment: Also, to anyone taking Atari's advice, I went ahead and stupidly (and blindly) added `iface eth1 inet dynamic` to my `/etc/network/interfaces` file and it mucked up my boot and I had to drop down to recovery mode to fix it...do not make the same mistake I made.

Comment: Yea, I guess I should have looked at the configuration you made a little closer. Well, know you know how to mess with the networkmanager! lol

Comment: This is not an acceptable answer in cases where you don't have connection to the internet :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems I am a little late, but still:
Since I think 12.04 you are screwed if you want to invest little work and get stuff done via the old /etc/network/interfaces.

But there's hope ! :D

Just use /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/**CONNECTIONS**

If you take a standard system connected via ethernet the file usually looks like this:

filename: Wired connection 1

content:

```
[802-3-ethernet]
duplex=full
mac-address=xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

[connection]

```
id=Wired connection 1
uuid=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
type=802-3-ethernet
timespamp = xxxxxxxxxx
```

[ipv6]

```
method=auto
```

[ipv4]

```
method=manual
dns=192.168.0.1
address=192.168.0.123/24,192.168.0.1
```

Comment: what happened in 12.04

Answer (score 1):

I found this is easily done on your router. I don't know what type of router you may have but there should be an option where you can have your MAC address map to a specific IP address on your LAN. This is the setup I have...

Comment: Usually you are right, and eventually I will move to using my linux as my router, but many routers, like the one I am currently using, do not support address mapping.

Comment: The option is called DHCP Reservation Lease Infos. It is by far the easiest thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. ssh works, a fixed IP is ok. Now the only thing missing is of course the dns. That's why you fail to get on the internet. Your gateway is 192.168.1.1 and that's presumably a router. Many of them provide dns, so simply try 192.168.1.1 as nameserver

Answer (score 1):

need the `auto eth0`, other than that once you have the code do a full reboot and the change will take place.

`ifconfig eth0 up`/`down` does not make the change.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `ifdown` and `ifup` use the `-v` option to print any error 
after that you should kill the `dhcp deamond` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (to open a terminal )  and type : `sudo killall dhcp` and enter your password .